# How to remove line on tapped point inside canvas in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, canvas, windows-phone-8

Im trying to draw a line with finger on windows phone canvas, i Done this but when i try to remove/clear that line it's Removing all Elements in that Canvas ,

```
ContentPanelCanvas.Children.Clear();
```

Hear is My Complete Code:

XAML

```
  <Canvas x:Name="ContentPanelCanvas" Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent"  Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <Grid Width="450" Height="600">
        <Button x:Name="clickMeBtn" Height="72"
                Width="200"
                Content="Click Me" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                VerticalAlignment="Center" Click="clickMeBtn_Click" />
         </Grid>
   </Canvas>
```

C# Code is Like this :

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ContentPanelCanvas.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(ContentPanelCanvas_MouseMove);
        this.ContentPanelCanvas.MouseLeftButtonDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(ContentPanelCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown);
    }

    void ContentPanelCanvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        currentPoint = e.GetPosition(ContentPanelCanvas);
        oldPoint = currentPoint;
    }

    void ContentPanelCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

            currentPoint = e.GetPosition(this.ContentPanelCanvas);

            line = new Line() { X1 = currentPoint.X, Y1 = currentPoint.Y, X2 = oldPoint.X, Y2 = oldPoint.Y };
            line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
            line.StrokeThickness = 10;
            this.ContentPanelCanvas.Children.Add(line);
            oldPoint = currentPoint;
    }

    private void clickMeBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello Every One ");
        ContentPanelCanvas.Children.Clear();

    }
```

Code is Executing Without Error , But it's Removing button to , How can i Remove Only Lines I Draw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the code is doing exactly what you wrote, it is clearing all children of the `ContentPanelCanvas`. If you only want to remove the lines, then only remove the lines:

```
foreach (var line in ContentPanelCanvas.Children.OfType<Line>().ToList())
    ContentPanelCanvas.Children.Remove(line);
```

Comment: I am using that for wp8.1 silverlight. Can I remove a point or portion from a line, not full line. Also I have a background image of canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 ContentPanelCanvas.Children.Remove(Line);
```

or remove children by index

```
ContentPanelCanvas.Children.RemoveAt(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you clear the canvas it will "[Removes all elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from a UIElementCollection."

You should create an event handler with line for example tap event handler , once tap you should hold the line control in another control to remove, then in button click handler remove it like this

```
ContentPanelCanvas.Children.Remove(controlToDelete);
```

controlToDelete is the control you hold to delete from the line tap handler i.e line control